# How to get response from API of GET method with arguments in python?

Tags: python-2.7, httprequest

There is one API `**http://172.25.0.1/listVideo.psp?count=20**`
Which give json response.

```
url = "http://172.25.0.1/getVideo.psp"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json"}
for key,value in headers.items():
    request.add_header(key,value)            
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
return response
```

So how to add argument? I have tried some code but that has been failed. So please help me to add argument **count=20**